# Find the line number of a tag in a HTML document

Tags: ruby

Currently I'm parsing a HTML document using Nokogiri and iterating through all the `code` tags like this:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
html.css("code").each do |code|
   # do something with code
   if /^@@@@/.match(code.text.split("\n")[0])
     return "this code element is at line blah"
   end     
end
```

I don't *have* to use Nokogiri, it was just convenient to use to iterate through all the code elements.

In the case where the `code` tag begins with `@@@@` then I want to be able to reference the line number in the document where that `code` tag occurred. Keep in mind that two code tags can be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons Nokogiri might be returning a line number of 0 for nodes retrieved using the HTML parser, both involving lbxml.

1. A bug in  version 2.7.3 of libxml

Credit: Aaron Paterson AKA tenderlove [https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/closed#issue/347](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/closed#issue/347)

2 . The version of Nokogiri that you are using is built against a different version of libxml than you currently have on your system.

This was my issue. I had libxml version 2.7.8 and was seeing this behavior. I had not installed the gem locally, so I went ahead and did that

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri
```

If you already have the gem install it would be just be 1 extra step to uninstall it

```
$ gem uninstall nokogiri 
$ gem install nokogiri
```

Credit - [Tin Man's Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363194/how-to-downgrade-libxml-2-7-8-to-2-7-6-in-ubuntu)

To determine the version of libxml you are currently running

```
$nokogiri -v
```

My current setup (working)

```
ruby: 
engine: mri
version: 1.8.7
platform: universal-darwin10.0

libxml: 
loaded: 2.7.8
binding: extension
compiled: 2.7.8
nokogiri: 1.4.4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was me who filed that issue. Good on you for taking the time to explain it as an answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open('./test.html', 'r'))

code_nodes = html.css('code').select{ |node| node.text[/^@@@@/] }
code_nodes.each do |node|

  # point to the end of the current line
  current_node = node.next 
  line_num = 0

  while (current_node) do
    # count line-endings
    line_num += current_node.text.count("\n")

    # get the previous node (AKA the one above this one.)
    current_node = current_node.previous 
  end

  puts line_num
end
```

where `test.html` looks like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <code>1</code>
    <code>@@@@2</code>
    <code>3</code>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is quick 'n dirty code that doesn't get it quite right, but I think the basic idea is sound. You need to find the nodes with "@@@@" in them, then walk backwards counting the text nodes that contain line-endings until you reach the top node.

Difficulty arises because using .previous() doesn't seem to get the previous_sibling() nodes, meaning that anything in the `<head>` block won't be counted if it exists. So, the logic in the while-loop probably needs to be aware of previous_siblings() and parent() nodes and the nodes they contain.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = <<-HTML 
<html>
<body>
  <code>1</code>
  <code>@@@@</code>
  <code>3</code>
  <code>@@@@</code>
  <code>
    @@@@
  </code>
</body>
</html>
HTML

puts doc.scan(/(.*?<code>)(\s*@@@@)/m).map { |match| match.first.scan(/\n/).size }.inject([1]){ |sum, n| sum << sum.last + n }[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that for *some unknown reason* that `Nokogiri::HTML` won't return the line number of any given element when you call the `line` method on it, but `Nokogiri::XML` **will**. Confusing, much?

Therefore, the solution is this:

```
html = Nokogiri::XML(html)
html.css("code") do |code|
  if /^@@@@/.match(code)
    parse_code(code)
  end
end

def parse_code(code)
  # do something and report back using:
  # Assume for a moment document.path exists.
  puts "Parsed code block on: #{code.line} of #{document.path}"
end
```