# How to downgrade libxml 2.7.8 to 2.7.6 in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri, libxml2

One of my Rubygem (Nokogiri) was bult against libXML 2.7.6, but once i upgraded libXML to version 2.7.8, my programs are giving errors. To make my programs working i need to do a lot of modifications and i don't want to do them. Can i downgrade libXML to 2.7.6

Answer (score 3):

Did you try rebuilding Nokogiri to use the newer version of libxml?

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
gem install nokogiri
```

should do it. If you installed Nokogiri using `sudo` originally you'll need to use it with the commands above too.

Nokogiri has native code that gets compiled at installation, and that code would be unhappy if the libxml version changed. Uninstalling, then reinstalling should only take about 30 seconds, resulting in the native code being updated for the new library.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this case is...

1. Download the source for the version of the lib I want to use
2. Use `apt-get build-dep libxml` to get the needed dependencies
3. Configure the downloaded lib to use a prefix like /opt or $HOME
4. Configure the app(s) that needs the "odd" version of the lib from source to use the downloaded version.
5. Build & Install

In some cases it is also possible for two libs to live side-by-side and can be managed via the package manager but I have had really bad luck with this.

Comment: Linux From Scratch is notorious for having packages that refuse to work with different libXML versions. I once had three installs going at once, and it was not too fun to keep track of all of them... I deleted on by accident, as I forgot to shove it into `/opt/`, but oh well... I do agree, though, that your answer works for people who compile stuff constantly or those who are downgrading a critical system package.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=321156. It's a guide on downgrading packages.

Also, migrate to https://askubuntu.com/. They handle Ubuntu stuff.

Comment: I'll throw in the warning that I've seen bad and terrible things happen when one tries to forcefully downgrade packages. I am not saying Blender is wrong at all but I am speaking from personal experience (perhaps bad luck but experience)

Comment: I usually look for newer versions of the conflicting packages, because I've killed an Ubuntu system by downgrading before...